# cshtml file converted into numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was editing my view in visual studio. PC restarted due to power cutt off. When I opened my file it was showing some thing like [image: this].

Can some one tell what was the problem? and how to solve it or it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on file in solution explorer, open with, and there select html editor and set it as default.